# Инвертирование числа

Tags: c++

Программа должна инвертировать число, но почему-то этого не происходит

```
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int mass[2];
    int result = 0;
    int num;
    int i = 0;
    cin >> num;

    while (num > 0)
    {
        mass[i] = num % 10;
        i++;
        num  = num / 10;
    }

    int f = 0;

    for (int g = sizeof mass - 1; g >= 0; g--)
    {
        result = (mass[f] * pow(10, g)) + result;
        f++;
    }

    cout << result << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А почему бы вам не поступить проще?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int num, res = 0;
    cin >> num;

    while(num)
    {
        res = res*10 + num%10;
        num /= 10;
    }

    cout << res << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Что до вашего кода...
Вы работаете только с двузначными числами? Если нет - у вас будет выход за границу `mas` со всеми вытекающими последствиями.
Далее - вставьте вот такой вывод в программу:

```
cout << sizeof mass << endl;
```

Судя по всему, результат вас удивит - он будет не 2, как вы, наверное, ожидали, а `2*sizeof(int)` - и вы опять получаете выход за границы массива.

Дальше, собственно, комментировать уже ничего не нужно :(

Comment: При всем уважении, @Harry, Вы что-то не то написали. Подставляю num = 5, и на выходе немедленно 5.

Comment: А что должно быть? Я так понимаю, вы хотите получать число, записанное в обратном порядке, нет?